# How to report Windows 10 bug without a Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10

I have a bug on the Windows 10 Printer Interface.

[image: Screenshot of bug]

Is it possible to report this bug without being logged into a Microsoft account or using the MS app?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/368667/how-to-report-a-problem-or-send-feedback-about-windows-10/

Comment: Are you running Insider Updates or the regular releases? Have you checked for an installed the latest drivers for your computer?

Comment: The answer to your question, that in order to provide feedback of any kind to Microsoft, it requires an account of some kind.  Microsoft does not allow unregistered users to provide feedback (this extended to any Microsoft application and/or GitHub project).

Comment: @music2myear I running Windows 10 pro 1903 64 bit, automatically upgraded by Windows update.